# Magento2 - PayPal Credit/Debit is not working

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal-payflow-pro

I have `enabled` PayFlow Pro.

Paypal Credit/debit is not working.

When we enter payment details it does not take them.  Says to enter the valid credit card info.

Anyone have idea about this error.

Please help.